# If $E=A\cap B$ for $A$ closed and $B$ open then every point has a neighbourhood $U$ such that $U\cap E$ is closed in $U$

Tags: general-topology

I am asked to prove the following thing. However, I am a bit confused about what is open and what is closed...

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $E\subset X$. If $E=A\cap B$ with $A$ open in $X$ and $B$ closed in $X$ then for all $x\in E$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $E\cap U$ is closed in $U$.

Any hint?

Comment: I think you can just take $U=A$.

Comment: $U$ induced topology? or maybe $E\cap U$ is closed in $X$ in your question.

Comment: $E\cap U$ is closed in $U$ with the induced topology.

Comment: if $U=A$ i doubt how to prove $E\cap U=(A\cap B)\cap A=A\cap B$ is closed in $A$?

Comment: The A complement of A cap B is A\B which is open within the big space and the A subspace.  Since the A complement of A cap B, is open within A, A cap B is closed within A.